# Best practices for nested async inside of ngFor?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, async-pipe, angular-ngfor

Let’s say I have a list of cars:

```
const cars: Array<{carId: number}> = [{carId: 1}, {carId: 2}];
```

And I render them in a template:

```
<div *ngFor=“let car of cars”></div>
```

Inside of that template, I want to get some dynamic image paths from a method that returns an observable:

```
<div *ngFor=“let car of cars”>
    <img [src]=“getImagePath(car) | async”>
</div>

getImagePath(car: {carId: number}): Observable<string> {
   return //some service request that brings back a url based on the carId
}
```

For state management and storage, I’m using Firebase. All of my images are stored in a bucket and I can get to them by providing my service with a carId that uses it to fetch the downloadURL.

I want to avoid updating Firestore with downloadURL’s when the file is first saved because I’d be storing them in sub-collections and pulling them out of there is already a pain due to the nature of Firestore.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently? The code above would most certainly bring the browser to a crawl if the list starts to grow … right?

Comment: maybe I don't understand; but why do you think that browser will come to a crawl? Obviously, if you have a large list of cars, you will get many `div`s; and then you will be downloading many images... but that's the nature of the page that you are building (if you don't paginate) - *not* the inefficiency of Angular code. Also, I didn't get how Firestore is relevant to your question

Comment: Wouldn’t it though? What if I have a hundred cars? Isn’t that a hundred active subscriptions while the DOM is rendering? I only mentioned Firebase to avoid responses that would suggest storing the image paths and including them in the car object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a request directly on every **img** element, you can just make it into an observable and subscribe to it once then display the returned array to your html.

I used a couple of RXJS operators to get what you want.

- `mergeMap` to flatten the inner observable
- `of` to convert the ***cars*** array into an observable
- `map` to transform the ***cars*** array into a a new array with their corresponding car image path
- `forkJoin` - we wrapped multiple requests into one observable and will only return when a response has been received for all requests.

*This is certainly only one way to do it and there might be other better ways.*

```
getCarImages() {
  const cars: Array < {
    carId: number;
  } > = [{
      carId: 1,
    },
    {
      carId: 2,
    },
  ]; 
  of(cars)
  .pipe(
      mergeMap((e) => {
        return forkJoin(
          e.map((item) => this.apiService.getCarImages(item.carId))
        ).pipe(
          map((paths) => {
            console.log(paths);
            return e.map((car, index) => ({
              ...car,
              imagePath: paths[index],
            }));
          })
        );
      })
    )
    .subscribe((res) => {
      this.cars = res;
      console.log(this.cars);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let car of cars">
  <img [src]="car?.imagePath" />
</div>
```

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjqxet?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to mock the solution.

Comment: @katysha - I think your approach is much simpler and better